# Process finished with exit code instead of returning back to main function

Tags: c, linked-list

I am creating an grocery store system as an assignment in C for a class I put off until my senior year. It uses a linked list to keep track of products in the store. I have gotten it mostly working, but for some reason each time I select a menu option, it will run until it tries to access a NULL memory location (Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)) and exit with some random memory location that it tried to access instead of returning back to the main function.

I have tested out several different while loop conditionals, all of which lead to the process being terminated as it seems like NULL is accessed even if the conditional isn't met.

The program has two classes, both of which are below. I am trying to focus on the "showList" function for now, as I feel like if I'm able to figure one out, then I can correct the rest of them.

showList() is called by option 4 on the menu.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "list.h"

void displayMenu()
{
puts("Welcome to the LinkedList grocery store.");
puts("Please let me know what you want to do by typing in one of the 
numbers.");
puts("============================================================");
puts("1: Add product to store           2: Purchase product from store");
puts("3: Check price of a product       4: Show products in store");
puts("5: Remove a product from store        6: Find product");
puts("7: Inventory       8: Done for today");

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
product * head = NULL, *p;
char temp[N];
float sales = 0.0, quantity;
int choice, done = 0;
//system("cls");

  head = load(head, "inventory.txt");
  while (!done) {
    displayMenu();
    puts("What do you want to do?");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    fflush(stdin);

    switch (choice)
    {
        case 1:
            head = addProduct(head);
            break;
        case 2:
            fflush(stdin);
            printf("Please enter the name of a product: ");
            fflush(stdin);
            scanf("%s", temp);
            fflush(stdin);
            printf("Please enter the quantity: ");
            fflush(stdin);
            scanf("%f", &quantity);
            fflush(stdin);
            sales += purchase(head, temp, quantity);
            break;
        case 3:
            fflush(stdin);
            printf("Please enter the name of a product: ");
            fflush(stdin);
            scanf("%s", temp);
            fflush(stdin);
            checkPrice(head, temp);
            break;
        case 4:
            showList(head);
            break;
        case 5:
            fflush(stdin);
            printf("Please enter the name of a product: ");
            fflush(stdin);
            scanf("%s", temp);
            fflush(stdin);
            rmItem(head, temp);
            break;
        case 6:
            fflush(stdin);
            printf("Please enter the name of a product: ");
            fflush(stdin);
            scanf("%s", temp);
            fflush(stdin);
            findProduct(head, temp);
            break;
        case 7:
            puts("****INVENTORY****");
            fflush(stdin);
            printf("Total sales: %f\n", sales);
            fflush(stdin);
            display(head);
            break;
        case 8:
            doneToday(head, "inventory.txt");
            done = 1;
            break;
        default:
            puts("Wrong code. Please try again.");
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

List.c:

```
#include "list.h"

// load in data from a file appending to the list l, return it
product * load(product *l, char fn[])
{
char name[N], quantity_unit[N], price_unit[N];
float quantity_value, price_value;

int rt;
product * head = l;
FILE * fin = fopen(fn, "r");

if(fin == NULL) {
    printf("InLoad: File open failed (%s)\n", fn);
    return NULL;
}

while (1) {
    rt = fscanf(fin, "%s %f %s %f %s\n", name, &quantity_value,quantity_unit, 
&price_value, price_unit );
    if (rt < 5)
        break;
    if (head == NULL)
        head = buildNode(name, quantity_value, quantity_unit, price_value, 
price_unit);
    else
        append(head, buildNode(name, quantity_value, quantity_unit, 
price_value, price_unit));
}
fclose(fin);
return head;
}

void doneToday(product* l, char fn[])
{
FILE * fout = fopen(fn, "w");
if(fout == NULL) {
    printf("InSave: File open failed (%s)\n", fn);
    return;
}
product* current = l;
while(current != NULL){
    fprintf(fout, "%s %f %s %f %s\n", current->name, current- 
>quantity_value,current->quantity_unit, current->price_value, current- 
>price_unit);
    current = current->next;
}

fclose(fout);

}

// build a product Node
product * buildNode(char name[], float quantity_value, char quantity_unit[], 
float price_value, char price_unit[])
{
product * p =  (product *) malloc(sizeof(product));
if(p == NULL) {
    puts("InBuildNode: Memory Allocation Failed!");
    return NULL;
}

strcpy(p->name, name);
p->quantity_value = quantity_value;
strcpy(p->quantity_unit, quantity_unit);
p-> price_value = price_value;
strcpy(p->price_unit, price_unit);

return p;
}

//shows the current product list
void showList(product *l)
{
product* cursor = l;
puts("************ Product List ******************");
printf("Name\tQuantity\tUnit\tPrice\t\tUnit\n\n");


    while(cursor != NULL){
        printf("%s\t%f\t%s\t%f\t%s\n", cursor->name, cursor->quantity_value, 
cursor->quantity_unit, cursor->price_value, cursor->price_unit);
        cursor = cursor->next;
    }


}

//adds a product to the list if it's not already
product * addProduct(product* l)
{
product* cursor = l;
product* result = l;
char name[N];
float quantity_value;
char quantity_unit[N];
float price_value;
char price_unit[N];

puts("Please enter the name of a product: ");
scanf("%s", name);
puts("Please enter the quantity value of a product: ");
scanf("%f", &quantity_value);
puts("Please enter the quantity unit of a product: ");
scanf("%s", quantity_unit);
puts("Please enter the price value of a product: ");
scanf("%f", &price_value);
puts("Please enter the price unit of a product: ");
scanf("%s", price_unit);

while(cursor != NULL){
    if(name == cursor->name){
        cursor->quantity_value += quantity_value;
        printf("The product with name **%s** already exists.", name);
        printf("The quantity was updated. New quantity is: %f", cursor- 
>quantity_value);
        return result;

    }
    cursor = cursor->next;

}

if(!cursor){
    result = append(l, buildNode(name, quantity_value, quantity_unit, 
price_value, price_unit));
    puts("New product added successfully!");
}

return result;

}

product * append(product *l, product * p)
{

product* cursor = l;

if(cursor == NULL){
    return p;

} else {

    while(cursor->next != NULL){
        cursor = cursor->next;
    }

    cursor->next = p;
    return l;
    }

}

void checkPrice(product* l, char p[])
{
product* cursor = l;

while(cursor->next != NULL){
    if(strcmp(cursor->name, p) == 0 ){
        printf("The current price of %s is %f %s", p, cursor->price_value, 
cursor->price_unit);
    }
    cursor = cursor->next;
    }
}

void findProduct(product* l, char p[])
{
product* cursor = l;

while(cursor->next != NULL){
    if(strcmp(cursor->name, p) == 0){
        printf("Product Found: %s %f %s %f %s", cursor->name, cursor- 
 >quantity_value, cursor->quantity_unit, cursor->price_value, cursor- 
 >price_unit);
        return;
    }
    cursor = cursor->next;
}

printf("The requested product was not found.");
}

void display(product *l)
{
product* cursor = l;

printf("Product: \n");
    while(cursor){
        printf("%s %f %s %f %s\n", cursor->name, cursor->quantity_value, 
cursor->quantity_unit, cursor->price_value, cursor->price_unit);
        cursor = cursor->next;

    }

}

float purchase(product* l, char p[], float q){
product* cursor = l;
float dollars = 0.0;

while(cursor->next != NULL){
    if(strcmp(cursor->name, p) == 0){
       if(cursor->quantity_value > q){
           dollars = cursor->price_value * q;
           cursor->quantity_value -= q;
           printf("Sale Completed, dollars made: %f\n", dollars);
           return dollars;
       } else if(cursor->quantity_value < q){
           dollars = cursor->price_value * cursor->quantity_value;
           printf("Sale partially completed, dollars made: %f\n", dollars);
           rmItem(l, cursor);
           return dollars;
       }
    }
}

printf("The sale was not completed, maybe the product doesn't exist.");
return dollars;

}

void rmItem(product* l, char p[])
{
product * current = l;
product * previous = current;
while(current != NULL) {
    if (strcmp(current->name, p) == 0) {
        if(previous == current)  // the first node
            l = (current->next);
        else // not the first one
            previous->next = current->next;

        free (current);
        return;
    }
    previous = current;
    current = current->next;
    }
}
```

list.h:

```
    #ifndef PROJECT3_LIST_H
#define PROJECT3_LIST_H
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 20

struct product
{
    char name[N];
    float quantity_value;
    char quantity_unit[N];
    float price_value;
    char price_unit[N];
    struct product *next;
};

typedef struct product product;

product * load(product *l, char fn[]);
product * buildNode(char name[], float quantity_value, char quantity_unit[], 
float price_value, char price_unit[]);
void showList(product *l);
product * addProduct(product* l);
product * append(product *l, product * p);
void checkPrice(product* l, char p[]);
void findProduct(product* l, char p[]);
void display(product *l);
float purchase(product* l, char product[], float q);
void rmItem(product* l, char p[]);
void doneToday(product* l, char fn[]);




#endif //PROJECT3_LIST_H
```

Comment: Flushing input does not realiably achieve what you think. You need to redesign around that. This might even be the cause of your problems, but it is not portable, so i cannot test. You have to.

Comment: Why does `cursor->next` being `NULL` prevent an item being printed?

Comment: Should I avoid using fflush period then? I was under the impression that the buffer needed to be flushed whenever input was captured. I wish my professor was clear about this. I'll go ahead and remove them, and give it a go.        
That's a very good question, I'll remove the conditional down to just while(cursor){} EDIT: Changing the conditional to while(cursor != NULL) or while(cursor) provides the same outcome and previous.

Comment: It needs to be emptied from anything which could not be read at last reading attempt. That however cannot be done by flushing. You either need to know enough about it so that you can correctly ignore it (by reading and then not using it), or you need to read everything and only THEN interpret it. Here is a very good, though slightly cynical-sounding article: http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html

Comment: Most importanlty, `scanf()` as a return value for a reason, you ignore it at your own risk. Read the docu, predict the return value in case of success, then check that you get it.

Comment: Your program crashed, which is why execution stopped. You need to solve that problem. Time to fire up the debugger.

Comment: If `rmItem(head, temp);` is a function to remove an item, it is not changing `head`. Unlike `head = addProduct(head);`

Comment: thank you for the document, I'll read through it and update back when I've gotten a grasp. the template for this was created by my professor so it looks like I'll have a leg up when I figure this out.

Comment: In showList() you do not need both `l` and `cursor`. Change the `l` parameter to `cursor` and get rid of the code line `product* cursor = l;`.  In the `while` delete `&& cursor->next !=NULL`, you just need to know the current position is not null. (You could use `for(;cursor;cursor=cursor->next)printf(...);` instead of the `while` construct. The only incorrect thing in `showList()` is stopping one short of the last item `&& cursor->next !=NULL`.

Comment: Other things in `main()` where is the `#define N` (perhaps in `"list.h"`) used to set the size of `temp[N]`. The same for `load(head, "inventory.txt");`, is `load()` defined in `"list.h"`? Cannot debug without all the code.

Comment: #define N is in list.h, along with the "product" structure. I will edit to include all the code.

Comment: @TedD. I have gone ahead and posted all of the code for this project.

Comment: The behaviour of `fflush()` is implementation defined because not all stream types will support the necessary control.  For example in Microsoft's C runtime library it will flush console input, but may not do for other compilers.  In Linux it is defined only for "seekable files", which does not include terminal streams.  There are portable means to achieve what you need but if you are using MS C, and this is a school assignment, and whoever is grading or examining has advised this then I would advise to continue for the purposes of passing a course, but know to avoid it in the real world.

Comment: Flushing is something you do to an output stream; flushing an input stream is implementation defined. If you really must, just accept the inputed characters and ignore them.

Comment: @NeilEdelman : Strictly it is _implementation defined_ rather then _undefined_.

Comment: Learn to use a debugger - a much better way of solving coding problems like this.  It would be helpful if you specifies what compiler and version you are using given the implementation defined behaviour you have.  Your code formatting is not conventional , consistent or conducive to being read and comprehended by others.